# Json_encode a merged array, but only returning 1 row

Tags: php, mysql

So this is my code, fetching the result of the query i need

```
$json_array = array();
$sql = "call rep_info();";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $json_array[] = $row;
}

mysqli_free_result($result);  
mysqli_next_result($connect); 

// Buat info user
$json_array2 = array();
$sql = "call rep_user();";

$result = $connect->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $json_array2[]["user"] = $row;
}
```

Then i merged the two arrays into one like this

```
$timeline = array_merge($json_array[0],$json_array2[0]);
$timeline2 = array_merge($json_array[1],$json_array2[1]);

$timeline = array_merge($timeline,$timeline2);
```

Encoded the merged array as well as echoing the variable

```
$encoded = json_encode($timeline);

echo $encoded;
```

So basically what i want is displaying 2 rows of the query result which is from json_array[0] and json_array[1]. But i only get 1 row in the echo result which the json_array[1] and json_array2[1].

What is the problem in this code? Thanks!

EDIT:

```
print_r($json_array[0]);
print_r($json_array2[0]);

Array
(
    [id] => 11087
    [message] => Late post.\nDarmo ramai lancar
    [latitude] => -7.292500019073486
    [longitude] => 112.7388916015625
    [image] => 1529894809620.jpeg
    [thumb] => 
    [sub_category] => 
    [is_need_respond] => 0
    [is_sticky] => 0
    [is_hidden] => 0
    [viewed] => 18
    [deleted_at] => 
    [created_at] => 2018-06-25 02:48:04
)
Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [id] => 621
            [name] => asd
            [username] => asd
            [verified] => 2
            [avatar] => icfab.jpg
            [level] => 10
        )

)
```

Comment: Can you supply examples of `$json_array` and `$json_array2` agter yo have loaded them from the database

Comment: @RiggsFolly edited the question!

Comment: I was actually interested in the PHP Arrays i.e. a `print_r()` or `var_dump()` and not the json encoded versions

Comment: @RiggsFolly There ya go, hope you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$timeline = $json_array[0];
$timeline['user'] = $json_array2[0]['user'];
$timeline2 = $json_array[1];
$timeline2['user'] = $json_array2[1]['user'];

$timeline = [$timeline, $timeline2];

$encoded = json_encode($timeline);

echo $encoded;
```

## EDIT

Assuming `$json_array` has the same length as `$json_array2` you can merge them like this

```
foreach($json_array as $idx => &$item)
{
  $item['user'] = &$json_array2[$idx]['user'];
}
echo json_encode($json_array);
```

## UPDATE

I am not sure why you do not understand this 1-line cycle. I will try to explain it as good as I can.

You have 2 arrays of the same length - `$json_array` and `$json_array2`.
You iterate over each element in the `$json_array` and look at the same array index in `$json_array2`. When you have the corresponding elements from both arrays - you simply copy the `user` key from the second array into the first one.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much and sorry for the late reply

Comment: Sorry but can you help me again? So apparently i need to produce 10 sets of data, so with this approach i'd need to make timeline1-timeline10. Do you have any idea to make a loop with this kind code?

Comment: Well, simply add one more dimension at the front - e.g. instead of `$json_array2[0]['user']` use `$json_array[2][0]['user']` and instead of `$json_array[0]` use `$json_array[1][0]`

Comment: And how can i merge all of them? e.g `
$timeline = [$timeline, $timeline2];` ? If i loop 10 times, how do i merge them?

Comment: It works exactly how i wanted! One last request, the code works nicely but i can't seem to understand it. If you have time, it would be awesome if you're willing to explain how it works to me!